# Error when inserting entities which extend an Abstract Entity

Tags: ios, core-data

I have the following entities:

- `User`. The common user entity with username, mail, etc.
- `ComputerUserWithAI`. Similar to user but it's controlled by the application.
- `Pick`. Contains a relation to `Game` and it should hold a picker.

Since a `Picker` can be an `User` or a `ComputerUserWithAI` I created an `Abstract Entity` called `Picker` and I made `User` and `ComputerWithAI` extend that `Picker` class.
Once I added the `Picker` entity I made `Pick` have a relation to the `Picker` entity called picker.

Everything went fine, but I can't insert a `ComputerUserWithAI` to a `Pick`. My code is like this:

```
ComputerUserWithAI *userWithAI = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"ComputerUserWithAI" inManagedObjectContext:ctx];
userWithAI.name = @"DeepBlue";

Pick *pick = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Pick" inManagedObjectContext:ctx];
pick.game = game;
pick.picker = userWithAI;
```

The error I get is the following:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Unacceptable type of value for
>   to-one relationship: property = "picker"; desired type = Picker; given
>   type = NSManagedObject; value =  (entity:
>   ComputerUserWithAI...

But when I do:

```
pick.picker = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Picker" inManagedObjectContext:ctx];
```

it does work.

I checked the generated classes from core data and they are extending the Abstract Entity correctly. What might be wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the error. The generated `Pick.h` had the following:

```
@class Picker
@interface Pick : NSManagedObject

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSManagedObject *game;
@property (nonatomic, retain) Picker *picker;
```

Changing it to:

```
@interface Pick : NSManagedObject

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSManagedObject *game;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSManagedObject *picker;
```

made everything work.

Try verifying the code generated by Xcode. This happened to me using Xcode 4.2.